# React Native ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: react-native

I am getting this crash, and having a hard time identifying the root cause.

```
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(EventDispatcher.java:113)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.applyUpdatesRecursive(UIImplementation.java:914)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.applyUpdatesRecursive(UIImplementation.java:899)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.updateViewHierarchy(UIImplementation.java:639)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.dispatchViewUpdates(UIImplementation.java:594)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.onBatchComplete(UIManagerModule.java:799)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.onBatchComplete(NativeModuleRegistry.java:119)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$BridgeCallback.onBatchComplete(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:171)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

This issue was reported on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29759) but closed without proper resolution.

The code is written in JS, not sure what is triggering this native crash. The issue is not reproducable.

Comment: I have faced this issue in native Android dev when modifying an array while it is being rendered.  The github issue you linked points to that as well.  Do you mutate arrays inside any of your render functions?

Comment: Didn't find any mutation in my JS code. This is happening right after screen orientation change, not sure if its related though